# Amazon Product Advertising API ItemLookup update old ASINs

Tags: api, amazon-product-advertising-api

I have a list of ASINs that I want to get the `Large` and `Offers` responseGroups for from the Amazon Product Advertising API. However, when I try to do an `ItemLookup` for that, I don't get back the offers. When I visit the product URL in my web browser, the ASIN in the details section is diffrent from the one in the ItemLookup. I think the ASIN has been updated, but I don't know how to update all my other ASINs without scraping amazon.com or manually updating them.

Example: ASIN: `B06XJZT5KR` ([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XJZT5KR))

I POST to `http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&SubscriptionId=xxxxxxxxx&AssociateTag=xxxxxxxxx&ItemId=B06XJZT5KR&IdType=ASIN&ResponseGroup=Large,Offers`

Searching through the [raw XML response](https://pastebin.com/raw/wsddctuU), I don't get the price.

However, if you look at the product description section (see below), you see a diffrent ASIN: `B06XKGGYWC`.

When I post to *that* ASIN, I get the correct offer data.

---

I am not allowed to post more than 2 links, so the link to the product description is https:/ and /www.ama and zon.com/dp/B06XJZT5KR#productDescription combined.